# Visual indicator for nautilus when browsing remote file system?

Tags: nautilus, indicator

When using terminal(byobu), there is modeline to indicate whether we are looking at local system files or remote files like this.

Local:
[image]

Remote:
[image]

This is quite useful if you are shuffling between local/remote as there is visual indication.

How to get some visual indicator for nautilus while accessing remote files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The icon for a remote folder in the folder trail is different:

[image]

The different icon is shown for the root folder, where the name of the server is shown instead of `/`, and for the home directory of the connecting user.

Comment: Interesting, never observed that.